# C# update List[] items from another class

Tags: c#

I'm really stuck on this problem.  I have two classes, Person and Expense.  Person has property MyName with List Expense as member.  In Expense class, it has property MyFoodCost.  I have a Form that allows me to enter/update my expense for MyFoodCost.  In the Form, I have List Person because there will be more one person.  So if I want to update the MyFoodCost expense for specific person, how can I do that?  Will this specific person has the new update cost of MyFoodCost?

```
public class Expense
{
    private decimal MyFoodCost;

    public Expense(decimal food)
    {
        MyFoodCost = food;
    }

    public decimal FoodCost
    {
        set
        {
            MyFoodCost = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return MyFoodCost;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private string MyName;
    public List<Expense> MyExpense;

    public Person(string name, decimal food)
    {
        MyName = name;
        MyExpense = new List<Expense>();
        MyExpense.Add(new Expense(food));
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        set
        {
            this.MyName = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return this.MyName;
        }
    }
}

public partial class BudgetForm : Form
{
    public List<Person> person;

    public BudgetForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        person = new List<Person>();
    }

    private void buttonAddExpense_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal food = 0;

        food = decimal.Parse(TextBoxFood.Text);

        string name = ComboBoxPerson.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if(person.Count == 0)
        {
            person.Add(new Person(name, food));
        }
        else
        {
            Person you = person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == name);
            if (you == null)
            {
                person.Add(new Person(name, food));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in person)
                {
                    //check if person exists?
                    if (item.PersonName == name)
                    {
                        //person exists so update the food cost for him only.
                        //should i code to update the food
                        //or do somewhere else?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already found the `Person` object. I think you want to just add the new expense to that person's expense list. Something like this:

```
Person you = person.First(x => x.FullName == name);
if (you == null)
{
    person.Add(new Person(name, food));
}
else
{
    you.MyExpense.Add(new Expense(food));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct.  Thank you so much.  I add "you.MyExpense.Clear()" before "you.MyExpense.Add(..)" to get the new food cost to at index 0, otherwise it will keep adding to the list with old food cost in there as well.

Comment: please another question.  How can I loop through the Person list and Expense to display back in the BudgetForm?

Comment: If you are only keeping track of total expenses, why do you need it to be a `list`? just make it a `decimal`

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop I guess. something like `foreach (var p in person) { //do display here }`

Comment: Thanks, I just remove the list of Expense now.

Comment: I'm able to do in foreach() loop now after removing List<Expense>.